# Possible to tracert Google Voice calls, if I route my phone# voIP on Linux? Linux Mint Rosa 17

Tags: linux-mint, voip, traceroute

Wondering if it's possible to tracert anonymous voip calls I'm receiving if I connect my phone number to a Linux voIP server (Asterisk, sipX, OpenPBX, etc.)? My idea is that I may receive info from those calls that I can then run tcp cmd against to discover at least the home output server location. I'm a target of cyberstalking, and believe the intruder is using Google Voice. I have a basic mobile phone with no data. (Possible complication: he's already claimed MY Google Voice account, to which my current phone number is attached).

Comment: Not without access to the stalkers SIP registration server.

Comment: Would his voip SIP reg server be different than his home internet? I already traced his approximate IP address (neighborhood), and DNS (by way of email header). If he's using his home internet to make the voIP calls, can I tcp with that info + his voip phone number?

Comment: "Would his voip SIP reg server be different than his home internet?" It depends on who his VoIP provider is. It may not even be in the same country.